# Difference between spring-boot:repackage and mvn package

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

After reading Spring documentation and some other articles on web, I am still confused what is the difference between Spring Boot Maven plugin's **spring-boot:repackage** and a regular **mvn package**.

I've thought that mvn package creates a jar with all dependencies included, so what is really the reason to use the plugin by Spring?

Comment: `I've thought that mvn package creates a jar with all dependencies included`. <- this is wrong, mvn package only packages the module resources and classes.

Comment: Adding to @Tome 's response: "..unless your POM is a child of `spring-boot-starter-parent`", in which case `mvn package` will run the `spring-boot:repackage` goal thus creating the fat JAR.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**The maven package goal and the spring-boot:repackage goal are different** in nature. The spring-boot repackage goal is mainly intended to make a JAR or WAR executable from the command line itself using `java -jar *.jar` while the `maven package` goal take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.It is the spring-boot repackage goal that repackages the JAR produced by maven to specify the main class and make it ***executable*** using an ***embedded container***.

***Maven Package***

> - The first, and most common way, to set the packaging for your project via the equally named POM element . Some of the
>     valid packaging values are jar, war, ear and pom. If no packaging
>     value has been specified, it will default to jar.
> - When a package is defined,each packaging contains a list of goals to bind to a particular phase ,the jar packaging will bind the
>     following goals to build phases of the default lifecycle :
>     process-resources,compile,process-test-resources,test-compile,test,package,install,deploy.

***Spring-boot:repackage***

Plugin to be included is :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The configuration repackages a jar or war that is built during the package phase of the Maven lifecycle.

So,Once spring-boot-maven-plugin has been included in your pom.xml, ***it automatically tries to rewrite archives to make them executable by using the spring-boot:repackage goal***. You should configure your project to build a jar or war (as appropriate) by using the usual packaging element.

Reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html

Comment: Why it will automatically bind to package phase if set the repackage goal here?

Answer (score 7):

Spring repackage a jar or war that is built during the package phase of the Maven lifecycle. The following example shows both the repackaged jar, as well as the original jar, in the target directory:

```
$ mvn package
$ ls target/*.jar
target/myproject-1.0.0.jar target/myproject-1.0.0.jar.original
```

If you don’t include the  configuration, you can run the plugin on its own (but only if the package goal is used as well). For example:

```
$ mvn package spring-boot:repackage
$ ls target/*.jar
target/myproject-1.0.0.jar target/myproject-1.0.0.jar.original
```

See more details from spring website using the [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html)

Comment: If you use the ```<packaging>jar</packaging>``` directive, you can generate an executable self-sufficient jar: ```java -jar target/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar```

Comment: sorry, I didn't get the difference here...so you jave the same output in both cases?

Answer (score 2):

mvn package creates a jar or war.

The spring boot plugin takes that jar or war and repackages them to make them executable from the command line (i.e. no app server needed).

From the plugin docs:

"Repackages existing JAR and WAR archives so that they can be executed from the command line using java -jar."

Comment: Ok, so I thought that this is done by regular package as well. Am I correct now, that you cannot just java -jar a regular package? What else should be done with that regular package in order for it to be executable? What is it that spring-boot plugin does to that regular package exactly? I am sorry if I seem confused I just didn't understand it from their documentation.