# Spring boot maven plugin : goals and phase

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

This question may be more related to Maven in general than Spring Boot but there is something I don't understand.

I'm using Spring boot maven plugin. It has different goals (help, repackage, start etc...)

When it comes for example to repackage goal, I can see that on official Spring documentation :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is this goal already bound to a specific phase of Maven's lifecycle ?

Basically what is the point of the snippet above ?
Why not just using this :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And If I need to run repackage goal : just doing `spring-boot:repackage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as explicit as it can get in the documentation, right below the example you linked, as seen [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging):

> The example above repackages a jar or war archive that is built during the **package phase of the Maven lifecycle**...

Of course bonding that goal to the `package` phase, means that the typical `mvn clean install` will run all *other* goals from all *other* phases, up to `package` (`validate`, `compile`, `test`); unlike your `spring-boot:repackage`.

Comment: OK thanks but if spring-boot:repackage is already bound to package phase, why secifying it again in pom.xml with <execution> tags ?

Comment: @AntonBoarf it is not _already_ bound, the documentation and sample says that it _does_ bound it when you add that `goal`.

Comment: OK thanks, I thought when you wanted to bind you had to add a <phase>package</phase> tag inside the <execution>

Answer (score 1):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56184071/10335389) out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56184071/10335389

You can still add `spring-boot:repackage` to Maven's package command but it is just convenient to have the Jar file executable when using `mvn package`.

This might be a handy resource to look at: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-repackage-vs-mvn-package